# How to store and compare current and previous category IDs in JavaScript and nullify subcategory if they differ

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set store current category id in one variable, and if category changes then store that also and wants to compare that both id, if both is not equal then set sub cat=null, I don't know where am I doing wrong

I have tried using using JavaScript , but both ids are coming same

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  myFunction();
  function myFunction() {
    var previousCategory = $("#selectcategory").val();
    var category_id = previousCategory;
    var category_id = $("#selectcategory").val();
    var subcat_id = $("#selectsubcat").val();
    console.log(previousCategory, category_id);
    if (category_id !== previousCategory) {
      $("#selectsubcat").val(null);
      subcat_id = null;
    }
    // console.log(category_id, subcat_id);
  }
  $("#search").keyup(myFunction);
  $("#selectsubcat").on("change", myFunction);
  $("#selectcategory").on("change", myFunction);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code 'previousCategory' and 'category_id' get same value.  For example previousCategory='5' and category_id = '5'.
If condition says if both the id's are not same then it should set null in 'selectsubcat'. Right?